# How to Combine multiple png icon files into 1 transparent iconset

Tags: merge, png

What program  can combine multiple transparent png icon files into one transparent iconset like this example?

http://www.thaicreate.com/upload/stock/20120312060014.jpg

Comment: Do you want to develop such program or are you looking for an existing one (in which case your question doesn't belong here)?

Comment: I just looking for a software to do that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming related Q&A site. If you are looking for some software try asking on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Try [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop).

Comment: How can i do? Thank for answer.